# Nice piece of fish - What does that mean?

Tags: meaning, slang

I just watched this recap https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Q9nQXdzNd0, and I Erlich said "Nice piece of fish", Is it slang? Please, help me to get the clear meaning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just a jab at the other man's age.

In the US, many older people eat fish either because it's easy to chew and/or considered healthier than red meat.